# @AutowiredでインジェクトしたUserServiceがnullになってしまう

Tags: java, spring-boot

#### 実現したいこと

※teratailでも同様の質問をしています。ご了承ください。
https://teratail.com/questions/319227

現在Spring Bootを使用して予約サイトを作成しています。
今実現したいことは、自作のバリデーションを作成し、ユーザー登録を行う際にユーザーID・パスワードが既に登録されていないかをチェックし登録されていたらエラーメッセージを表示させたいです。

開発環境: Eclipse
Javaのバージョン: 11
Spring Bootのバージョン: 2.4.0

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

ConstraintValidatorを実装したUserIdDuplicateCheckValidatorを作成しましたが、そこで@AutowiredしてインジェクトしたUserServiceインスタンスがnullになってしまいます。

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at mrs.app.user.UserIdDuplicateCheckValidator.isValid(UserIdDuplicateCheckValidator.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at mrs.app.user.UserIdDuplicateCheckValidator.isValid(UserIdDuplicateCheckValidator.java:1) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:180) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.SimpleConstraintTree.validateConstraints(SimpleConstraintTree.java:62) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:75) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.doValidateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:130) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:123) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:555) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:518) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:488) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:172) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreUpdate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.preUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:304) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:174) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
```

#### 該当のソースコード

UserIdDuplicateCheck

```
package mrs.app.user;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { UserIdDuplicateCheckValidator.class })
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UserIdDuplicateCheck {

    String message() default "{mrs.app.reservation.UserIdDuplicateCheckValidator.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};


    @Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR,
            ElementType.PARAMETER })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    public @interface List {
        UserIdDuplicateCheck[] value();
    }
}
```

UserIdDuplicateCheckValidator

```
package mrs.app.user;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import mrs.domain.model.User;
import mrs.domain.service.user.UserService;


public class UserIdDuplicateCheckValidator
        implements ConstraintValidator<UserIdDuplicateCheck, User> {

    private String message;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService; ★★ここが@Autowiredしてもnullになる★★

    @Override
    public void initialize(UserIdDuplicateCheck constraintAnnotation) {
        message = constraintAnnotation.message();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(User value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        String userId = value.getUserId();
        Boolean blResult = userService.checkDuplicate(userId);

        if(!blResult) {
            context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(message).addPropertyNode("userId").addConstraintViolation();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

UserService

```
package mrs.domain.service.user;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import mrs.domain.model.User;
import mrs.domain.repository.user.EditUserRepositoryJdbc;
import mrs.domain.repository.user.UserRepository;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    EditUserRepositoryJdbc userRepositoryJdbc;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public void saveOrUpdate(User user, String userId) throws DataAccessException {
        System.out.println("beforeFix: " + userId);
        System.out.println("fixed: " + user.getUserId());

        userRepositoryJdbc.update(user, userId);
    }

    public boolean checkDuplicate(String userId) {
        if (userRepository.countByUserId(userId) != 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

UserRepository

```
package mrs.domain.repository.user;

import javax.persistence.LockModeType;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Lock;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import mrs.domain.model.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    User findOneForUpdateByUserId(String userId);
    long countByUserId(String userId);

}
```

User

```
package mrs.domain.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

import mrs.app.user.UserIdDuplicateCheck;


//会議室予約システムを利用するユーザー情報を格納するテーブル
//Userエンティティー
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr")
@UserIdDuplicateCheck(message="このユーザーIDは既に登録されています")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @NotBlank(groups=ValidGroup1.class)
    @Email(groups=ValidGroup2.class)
    private String userId;

    @NotBlank(groups=ValidGroup1.class)
    @Length(min=4, max=100, groups=ValidGroup2.class)
    private String password;

    @NotBlank(groups=ValidGroup1.class)
    private String firstName;

    @NotBlank(groups=ValidGroup1.class)
    private String lastName;

    /**
    * 電話番号
    */
    @NotBlank(groups=ValidGroup1.class)
    @Pattern(regexp = "0\\d{1,4}\\d{1,4}\\d{4}", groups=ValidGroup2.class)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @NotBlank(groups=ValidGroup1.class)
    private String zipCode;

    /**
    * 住所
    */
    @NotBlank(groups=ValidGroup1.class)
    @Size(max = 200, groups=ValidGroup2.class)
    private String address;

    //@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NotBlank(groups=ValidGroup1.class)
    private String roleName;


    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getRoleName() {
        return roleName;
    }

    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

#### 試したこと

https://medium.com/@ssscripting/getting-autowired-fields-to-work-with-constraintvalidators-in-spring-boot-74424d5b0aaa

上記のサイトをもとにvalidationConfigクラスを作成し、Applicationクラスと同じパッケージ内に配置しました。の設定を行いましたが、nullのままでした。(正直に言うとあまりこの、validationConfigクラスが何を行っているのか理解しきれていません)
その後もひたすらググってみましたが、解決に至らずここで質問をさせて頂きます。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/319227) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます、マルチポストが問題視されているとは知りませんでした。質問本文に追記いたします。

Comment: 参照されているサイトが行っているのは、公式リファレンスの[3.7.2. Configuring a Bean Validation Provider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.3/reference/html/core.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring)の部分であり、やりたいことを行うための設定に間違いないと思います。質問文で言うところの「上記のサイトをもとにvalidationの設定を行」ったというのは、具体的にどういうコードでしょうか(質問文に追記してみてください)。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。了解しました、追記いたします。

Answer (score 0):

以下のようにUserクラスにある自作バリデーションの第二引数に、ValidGroupクラスを持たせるとエラー無く正常に動作しました。正直なぜValidGroupクラスを指定しないとValidatorクラスで@Autowiredされないのか理解していません。Springの仕様を理解しきれていないので自分でも調べていきますが、ご存じの方はもしよければご教授お願いします。m(__)m

```
//Userエンティティー
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr")
@UserIdDuplicateCheck(message="このユーザーIDは既に登録されています", groups=ValidGroup2.class)
public class User implements Serializable {
```

Answer (score 0):

行いたいのは

- [Spring BootでカスタムValidatorにInjectionしたい時の設定 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/tag1216/items/76b8c1087d6b4b83550b)

の後半部分だと思いますが、それは、次の設定で実現できます。
(リンク先の方法でも実現できるとは思いますが)

```java
import java.util.Map;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernatePropertiesCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer hibernatePropertiesCustomizer(final Validator validator) {
        return new HibernatePropertiesCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
                hibernateProperties.put("javax.persistence.validation.factory", validator);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

---

なお、[前述Qiita記事](https://qiita.com/tag1216/items/76b8c1087d6b4b83550b)の前半部分や質問文中でリンクされている[こちらの記事](https://medium.com/@ssscripting/getting-autowired-fields-to-work-with-constraintvalidators-in-spring-boot-74424d5b0aaa)の設定は、現行 Spring Boot では `spring-boot-starter-validation` を依存関係に追加すれば [`ValidationAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.5.5/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.java) によって自動設定されます(ので手動で設定する必要はないはずです)。